# using C# to assign a value into Visio's Shape.Text causing exception

Tags: c#, text, shapes, visio, comexception

```
doc = app.Documents.Add(fileInfo[i].FullName);
Vis.Shapes shapes = doc.Pages[1].Shapes;
for (int j = 1; j <= shapes.Count; j++)
{
    if (shapes[j].Text.StartsWith("getSomeThing"))
    {
         shapes[j].Text = "doSomething()";                            
    }
}
```

shapes[j].Text = "doSomething()"; this line will cause an exception, how to fix it?

It causes a **COMException**.

**Exception message** is "The requested operation is disabled".

**ErrorCode = -2032465766**

Comment: Probably some of your shapes have text protection...

Comment: @JleruOHeP How to remove the text protection?

Comment: shape.get_CellsSRC((short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,(short)VisRowIndices.visRowLock,(short)VisCellIndices.visLockTextEdit).FormulaU = "0"; //to remove protection

Comment: Thanks for @JleruOHeP.

I have fixed it.

Comment: You are welcome! Then I`ll add this suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is some shape with lock on text edit. You can remove that protection:

```
shape.get_CellsSRC((short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
                   (short)VisRowIndice‌​s.visRowLock,
                   (short)VisCellIndices.visLockTextEdit).FormulaU = "0"; //to remove protection
```

And it is better to "remember" old value and set it back after yours edits.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have a new Problem.How to edit a shape's Classifier role properties. The Classifier role properties will come out when you double click on the shape. Can I edit it in C#?